# Create a named temp file in Java

Tags: java, file

I want to be able to create a temporary text File in Java to display on screen, but using File.createTempFile() does not give me enough control over its name.

Any thoughts here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why do you need such control over the name of a temporary file?

That question aside, no you can't have full control over the name of the file generated by `createTempFile`. If you really need full control, you need to create a regular `File` instead.

You may want to make use of the following:

- `java.io.tmpdir` System property for temporary file directory
- `createNewFile()` to check for naming conflicts
- `deleteOnExit()`