# How to create html files in struts action?

Tags: java, struts2

I need to create two HTML files in my struts 2 action. Save these HTML files (can we have these files temporary).

Then compare these two HTML files for any differences in their content.

So, my questions are

1) How to create HTML files and is it possible to create them on the fly just temporary for the sake of comparison?

2) In second step once the two HTML files are created, I will need to compare the two HTML files and then send the resulting/compared HTML output back to the browser.

PS: I am using [Daisy Diff](http://code.google.com/p/daisydiff/) to compare the two HTML pages.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciable.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429612/create-a-named-temp-file-in-java may be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, HTML is just string data, so treat it as such. You can create the file using a StringBuilder for instance and call it on the page using the toString().

I would probably have two StringBuilders in my action class:

```
StringBuilder html1 = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder html2 = new StringBuilder();
```

Use whatever methods you want to create the HTML data, not sure what you're creating on the fly or how the data is getting input, and append it to your StringBuilder objects.

And to hold your return value a String

```
// let's assume html1 is the value that we choose to send back
// after the comparison magic is performed
String htmlResult = html1.toString();
```

** if you're creating the html in one shot, you could just use a String value instead.

From your JSP you would reference the value by doing:

```
<s:property value="htmlResult" escapeHtml="false" />
```